# Error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object ,while parsing facebook JSON in asp.net

Tags: json, facebook, exception, object-reference

I am using/reusing json.net to get facebook likes of a user and his/her friend's like. I am having this error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

In the following code, I have parsed facebook json three times and I have this exception raised the third time I have used it....in the **methoduserlikes** function to be precise...

I think the problem is in [var i].........it works fine the first two times but exeception occurs third time.....

kindly point out what seems to be the problem.....

```
        oAuth.AccessTokenGet(Request["code"]);
        global_token = oAuth.Token;
        if (oAuth.Token.Length > 0)
        {

            url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=" + oAuth.Token;
            url_friends = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=" + oAuth.Token;
            string json = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);
            string jsonfriends = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, url_friends, String.Empty);
            Label1.Text = oAuth.Token.ToString();

           JObject likes = JObject.Parse(json);
            string id = "";//user id
            string name = "";//user likes
            JObject friends = JObject.Parse(jsonfriends);
            string fid = "";
            foreach (var i in likes["data"].Children())       //Loop through the returned friends
            {
                id = i["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                name = i["name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                Label3.Text = Label3.Text + "<br/> " + name;
            }
            foreach (var i in friends["data"].Children())
            {
                fid = i["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                methoduserlikes(fid);              
            } 
        }
    }


}


public void methoduserlikes(string id)
{
    Label4.Text = Label4.Text + "<br/> " + id;
    string flike = "";
    string like_id = "";
    string flike_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/likes?access_token=" + global_token;
    string jsonfriend_like = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, flike_url, String.Empty);
    JObject friend_like = JObject.Parse(jsonfriend_like);

    foreach (var i in friend_like["data"].Children())
   {
       like_id = i["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
        **flike = i["name"].ToString().Replace("\"","");**  here the exception is raised

        Label5.Text = Label5.Text + "<br/> " + flike;
    } 
}
```

}